# WIX Merge Module : Trying to use $(var.Project.TargetFileName)

Tags: wix, wix3, votive

I have created a simple Wix 3 Merge Module in VS 2005 ( .wxs )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Module Id="TestMergeModule" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">
    <Package Id="ef2a568e-a8db-4213-a211-9261c26031aa" Manufacturer="Me" InstallerVersion="200" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder">
        <Component Id="Test_ModuleComponent" Guid="{1081C5BC-106E-4b89-B14F-FFA71B0987E1}">
          <File Id="Test" Name="$(var.Project.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.Project.TargetPath)" DiskId="1" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Module>
</Wix>
```

And I have added the project "Project" as a reference to this Merge Module, however I continue to get this error

> Error 7   Undefined preprocessor variable
>   '$(var.Project.TargetFileName)'.

Any suggestions, I am sure I am just missing the obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice dictates that you always assume this is your issue and it is not a bug, but after a lot of wasted time I though I would just check, and, it looks like it might be because this is not supported for C++ projects (which mine is )

From WIX3 [bug report page](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1975405&group_id=105970&atid=642714)

> Date: 2008-10-17 14:53 Sender:
>   jasongin Any C++ project is not
>   MSBuild. C++ projects in VS use a
>   different project system that is more
>   difficult to interoperate with. That's
>   why Votive v3 does not yet support
>   references to C++ projects. We know
>   C++ project references is an important
>   feature, but it's not done yet. The
>   work is tracked by feature request
>   1585281.

This is an [open feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1585281&group_id=105970&atid=642717).. but has been for a long time now it seems, so not sure if it will ever be fixed :-(

Comment: Can't be fixed until the Visual C++ team integrates correctly with MSBuild.